# HTML is not escaped in an ERB tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote the following code in a js.erb file:

```
var data = '<%= "#{@books.page_section_right}".html_safe %>';

// For example:
var data = '<%= "<h3>
<strong>A few things you should know:</strong>
</h3>
<ul>
<li>
<strong>The course auto will auto sign out if you are idle for more than 30 minutes. We can't keep it running all day.</strong>
</li>
<li>
<strong>Every now and then we'll ask you a security question just to make sure you didn't bribe your dog to do the class for you.<br></strong>
</li>
<li>
<strong>Lastly, when you get to the exam, make sure you have enough time where you won't be interrupted. You must  finish the exam in one session. More on this later.</strong>
</li>
</ul>".html_safe%>';

// Booklet js:
$('#mybook').booklet("add", "end", data);
```

As you can see, the string is not formed properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your HTML has a single quote, which breaks your JavaScript. (The syntax highlighting in your question shows exactly what the problem is.) You can use [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) to prevent this from happening:

```
var data = '<%= escape_javascript(@books.page_section_right.html_safe) %>';
```

or, shorter:

```
var data = '<%= j @books.page_section_right.html_safe %>';
```

Comment: I'm getting another problem is  var data = '<h3><strong>Okay, here\'s how this works...<\/strong>\n<\/h3>\n<ul><li><strong>This looks like a book, reads like a book. Simple right? (Don\'t worry, we have lots of pictures)<\/strong>\n<\/li>\n<li><strong>Each chapter has a tab. When you\'ve finished a previous chapter, the next one will unlock.<\/strong>\n<\/li>\n<li><strong>Unlocked chapters\' tabs are extended and clickable<\/strong>\n<\/li>\n<li><strong>You can\'t jump ahead in the course, but you can always jump back to anything you\'ve read before<\/strong>\n<\/li>\n<\/ul>';

Comment: In each end tag looks like <\/strong> instead of </strong>. Do you have any idea, to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why slashes are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Remove html_safe. That method tells Rails that the string is safe and doesn't require escaping.

Comment: Removing `safe_html` will not solve the problem. There will still be a single quote in his HTML, which breaks the JavaScript.

Comment: That was not clear when I answered the question. The title is still misleading at that since it clearly says that the HTML is not escaped and removing .html_safe WILL fix that problem ...